# How to work around Semantic-ui's invalid header markup?

Tags: html, semantic-ui

Semantic-ui's examples for their header component places a `div` tag inside an `h2` tag, which is not valid markup.

Changing the outer `h2` to a `div` is valid, but no longer styles the same (it's much smaller).

How are you handling this markup?

```
<h2 class="ui header">
  <i class="settings icon"></i>
  <div class="content">
    Account Settings
    <div class="sub header">Manage your preferences</div>
  </div>
</h2>
```

(from http://semantic-ui.com/elements/header.html)

Comment: I don’t know Semantic UI, but couldn’t you simply use a `span` instead of a `div` (keeping the `class`)?

Comment: yes you could, but you have to change the markup (add `br`'s), since `span` doesn't do newlines the same way `div` does, and you'd have to change the inner one, too ... so it's basically just rewriting their example. I was curious if anyone had sort of a bigger picture approach, since this type of markup appears in other places too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is to have your header visually the same as the one in the example, but with valid markup, all you need to do is do is change *h2* into *div* and specify the size (this will fix the issue of it being much smaller). `<h2 class="ui header">` corresponds to `<div class="ui large header">` so the valid code would be:

```
<div class="ui large header">
  <i class="settings icon"></i>
  <div class="content">
    Account Settings
    <div class="sub header">Manage your preferences</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I just took a look at Semantic UI's issue tracker and noticed [this one](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3020) which addresses this exact problem (not sure if you're the one who opened it). In short, in a future version of Semantic UI, the following should have the same result, but with using actual header tags:

```
<h2 class="ui header">
  <i class="settings icon"></i>
  <span class="content">
    Account Settings
    <span class="sub header">Manage your preferences</span>
  </span>
</h2>
```

The solution above with the *div* tag remains valid though, assuming you don't need to use an actual *h2* tag.

Comment: Yeah that's my report. For now I've gone with the same route he'll eventually do, which is keeping the h2 tag, and using span internally, but styling spans into blocks. Thanks for the input. Gonna mark this as the answer.